# Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that has been up running for months now. Everything was fine until I added this line in the UserRepository that extends MongoRepository: `List<User> findAllByUserName(List<String> usernames);`

Now I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:751) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.example.holidayplanner.HolidayPlannerApplication.main(HolidayPlannerApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.ReferenceLookupDelegate.computeReferenceContext(ReferenceLookupDelegate.java:139) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.ReferenceLookupDelegate.readReference(ReferenceLookupDelegate.java:108) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultReferenceResolver.resolveReference(DefaultReferenceResolver.java:74) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readAssociation(MappingMongoConverter.java:543) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:474) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:420) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:389) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:351) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:287) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:283) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:106) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3180) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2836) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2558) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2540) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:849) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:444) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:154) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:61) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:638) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.holidayplanner.user.UserConfig.lambda$commandLineRunner$0(UserConfig.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

I've tried fixing it by using the  `@Query` annotation :

```
    @Query("{ 'userName' : ?0 }")
    List<User> findAllByUserName(List<String> usernames);
```

I also tried adding `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` to application.properties. None of them worked

Answer (score 1):

If your argument is a collection, you may need to use `In` suffix, so that the query generated uses `$in: []`.

```
List<User> findAllByUserNameIn(List<String> usernames);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries

Answer (score 0):

I cant say if the `@Query` Annotation does also work with a `List<String>` but at least are you usign  the wrong Query the `$in` Operator is missing. Try it on this way and if it works also try it with a `List<String>`

```java
@Query("{ 'userName' : { $in : ?0 } }")
List<User> findAllByUserName(String[] usernames);
```